# How to use placeholders for "IN" in python mysql statements when using mysql.connector

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am using mysql.connector to query values from the database in python.
I need to write a select query with "IN" in the where clause.
I tried to pass the values as a list, tuple, etc.
But it is throwing the error that the *"Python 'data-type' cannot be converted to a MySQL type"*

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

analyticsdb = mysql.connector.connect(
  pool_name = 'analyticspool',
  pool_size = 10,
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database="analytics"
)

analyticsCursor = analyticsdb.cursor(dictionary=True)
gender_values = ['Male', 'Female']
registeredQuery = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uid) AS registered FROM `users` WHERE gender IN (%s)"
placeholders = (gender_values)
analyticsCursor.execute(registeredQuery, placeholders)
regCount = analyticsCursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: The parameter is inserted as solid string literal. For gender (2 values) use simple equiality. For multi-values CSV list use FIND_IN_SET() instead of IN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html the parameters need to be of type tuple and there should be one %s for each of them.
I would suggest the following changes:

```
gender_values = ('Male', 'Female')
registeredQuery = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uid) AS registered FROM `users` WHERE gender IN (%s, %s)"
placeholders = gender_values
```

Dynamic gender values

```
registeredQuery = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uid) AS registered FROM `users` WHERE gender IN ("
for i in range(len(gender_values)):
    if i< len(gender_values)-1:
        registeredQuery += " %s,"
    else:
        registeredQuery += " %s)"

placeholders = gender_values # or tuple(gender_values) if they are a list
```

Comment: Thank You. But for me gender_values are dynamic. It can be either 1, 2 or 3 values.

Comment: If dynamic is the only issue, you can build the registeredQuery dynamically too. I will edit my answer with the way to do it.